# Unrecognized font family on iOS simulator with React Native

Tags: react-native

I've added Linux Biolinum fonts (http://www.dafont.com/linux-biolinum.font, LinBiolinum_R.ttf, LinBiolinum_RB.ttf) to my React Native project. Android version is OK. But on iOS I always see error *"Unrecognized font family LinBiolinum_R"*.

[image]

My style is:

```
customFontRegular: {
    fontFamily: 'LinBiolinum_R',
},
```

I've tryied to rename font file and font family to "MyFont", but the error appears again on iOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: try 

    customFontRegular: {
        fontFamily: 'LinBiolinum R',
    },

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67880817/3437900

Comment: Double check you are not using the font file name. Instead double tap the font file and font family name will be the title of your widow, use that.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

On Android it takes the name of the file and you are done. On iOS however it is a bit more complex.

There are a few steps you should take:

- Double check the font files are included in the Target in XCode
- Make sure they are included in the step "Copy Bundle Resources" (add files, not folders)
- Include them in the Info.plist of the app
- Find the name of the Font through FontBook or with some log statements in your AppDelegate

Explained in more detail here:
http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: yes, I had similar problem was that the android uses name of the file but IOS uses "actual name" of the font (that can be different from the file name).

Comment: I've accepted the answer. I've checked name of fonts in the logs. Name of fonts should be LinBiolinum and LinBiolinumB. Thank you.

Comment: The above solution working for many fontFamily in my app, but in my case it showing error for a particular fontFamily. So weird. Kindly let me know any other method to know about the issue. I have done above steps.

Comment: Saved a lot of time, thank you so much. :) Is there a way to rename the "actual name" of the font?

Comment: You must add individual fonts into the copy bundle resources list, and cannot add a fonts folder to it. I tried, and it failed to find the font.

Comment: multi target should check your target

Comment: Adding to Build Phases and + item to Copy Bundle Resources saved me. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use viewDidLoad from the referenced article in react-native, but... I am not sure where to import UIFont from...

Comment: I had the naming issue and solved it by using the fullname of the font.ttf file by right clicking on it then get info

Comment: Great answer. Sorted out my similar font-based problem straightaway.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jpavley/6567674 this is how you log the fonts from the last point

Comment: In my case, I changed my target font location from "relative to path" -> "relative to group" and it works

Answer (score 31):

Implement the following code in your appdelegate file

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"Family name:  %@", name);
    }
}
```

**You should use FONT FAMILY NAME instead of your font file name like the following**

```
fontFamily: "FuturaBT-Book"
```

Comment: This worked for me! I put it in the AppDeletegate.M file inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, right before the return. You can see the logs in Xcode.

Comment: Where in Appdelegate?

Comment: this done not print Poppins family expcept this all are working

Comment: It helped me, I used a font file name, but inside TTF the name was different, without dashes. Thank you!

Answer (score 31):

Easy/Working solution 2021. React Native 0.64. XCode 12+

Add these lines in `ios/<ProjectName>/Info.plist`. Rebuild ios app. that's it!

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
      <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
      <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
      <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>Feather.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
      <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
      <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
      <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
      <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
      <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: If only it were that simple.

Comment: After adding this, be sure to 1. delete from simulator, 2. stop metro, 3. run something like: `rm -rf node_modules; watchman watch-del-all; rm -rf /tmp/metro-*; yarn install; cd ios; pod install; cd ..; react-native start --reset-cache`, 4. re-run simulator

Comment: That didn't work for me. Probably the answer is not clear enough. Please say where we add your code, at the end or in between etc

Comment: @William at the end is fine but before </dict> </plist>

Answer (score 28):

For people who have tried everything and are still facing this issue, this is a problem with the font's file naming,
You need to rename all of the fonts file name to its postscript name.
On mac I can open the font using fontbook and find this out.
[image: Look at the postscript name]

Once I renamed all the fonts name to their postscript name the error was gone and I was also able to use the font-weight css property to set the font weight.

Comment: You just saved my night, man. I never would have imagined this.

Comment: for Poppins its not working

Comment: This was it!! I was trying Open Sans Condesed font. It worked fine on android, but wasn't on iOS simulator. The actual file name which I donwloaded was "OpenSans_Condensed-Bold.ttf", which wasn't working. But after I installed that font on mac system and went to FontBook, as mentioned in this answer, I saw that the 'PostScript Name' was "OpenSansCondensed-Bold". Hence, just renamed the font file name to "OpenSansCondensed-Bold" from "OpenSans_Condensed-Bold.ttf", ran `npx react-native-asset`, rebuilt the app and it worked both in ios and android this time. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

For me, changing the name of the file to the name of the Font (displayed as I open the file) did it.

Comment: This worked for me as well, even if my font had a space in its name (which I thought would be problematic), it actually did not matter.

Comment: This was it for us also. ICOMOON had a setting to give the font a name. It was different than what I gave the file name and the json data name. I'm amazed that this mattered. If anyone else it experiencing this, make sure to set the font name BEFORE downloading the font package from icomoon or any other font creation software.

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your `package.json`

```
"rnpm":{
    "assets":[
        "./assests/fonts/"
    ]
}
```

and then run `react-native link` in command line

Comment: correct, but deprecated. see https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

Comment: Umm, ok @E.A.T, then what is the replacement method that accomplishes the same thing as `react-native-link` with an `rnpm` section?

Comment: the link i added offers instructions. in short, this is moved to `react-native.config.js`

Answer (score 7):

1. If you have custom fonts that you downloaded from internet, place them, e.g in
   `src/assets/fonts` folder.
2. Create a file that is called `react-native.config.js` in the root folder and write the following in it:

   - `module.exports = { assets: ['./src/assets/fonts'], };`
3. Link your fonts assets by running `npx react-native link` in the terminal

Comment: This is what worked for me, I forgot to `npx react-native link`.

Answer (score 6):

Just do these 5 steps. It saves my life. ^.^

1. Add folder fonts include your fonts (path: src/assets/fonts)
2. Paste this code in file package.json =>  "rnpm": {
   "assets": [
   "./assets/fonts/"
   ]
   }
3. Run cmd  react-native link
4. Open Xcode select Target -> Build Phases tab -> Copy Bundle Resources and add your font
5. Rebuild app Open Xcode build or run cmd react-native run-ios

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to link your fonts.
In the root of the project, create a file: `react-native.config.js`
Considering that your fonts are placed at `PROJECT_NAME/assets/fonts` add this to the new config file:

```js
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios:{},
        android:{}
    },
    assets:['./assets/fonts/'],
}
```

Now just link them:

```
npx react-native link

or for react-native + 0.69

npx react-native-asset
```

After this, your fonts should be already added in the `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` directory and in `Info.plist` for IOS.

Credits to [this blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-custom-fonts-react-native/).

Answer (score 3):

For IOS,

- Make sure you add fonts to resource **Copy Bundle Resources**
- Make sure you have folder **Resources** in Xcode, somehow it was deleted and you must create, import fonts to that folder manually
- Make sure using name of **Family** in Font book

Answer (score 3):

I fix by changing font file name into **Futura-Medium**, if I use **FuturaMedium** it will error like above

Answer (score 3):

1. if there is no assets and font directories create them !
2. add your fonts to `assets/font/` which you created
3. add your root directory `react-native.config.js` file
4. change `react-native.config.js` file to this;

> ```
> module.exports = {
>     assets: ['./assets/fonts']
> }
> ```

5. Link your fonts and assets to react-native so run this command

> `npx react-native link`

6. Use your fonts where you want so change your stylesheet like;

> `fontFamily: 'texgyreadventor-regular'`

be carefull ! if your font have not bold version than remove

> `fontWeight: 'bold'`

from your stylesheet class

7. remove your app in simulator or in your physical device. Than re-build it. Because you have to re-build your app not refreshing it to see new fonts !

Comment: This did work for me once - on a clean RN install. But god help you if you're dealing with this further down the road. IOS is a ripe piece of shit that fails everytime you look at it.

Comment: Yes bro... you are right

Comment: You have a typo in step 2. It is plural fonts - not singular.

Answer (score 2):

*Easy solution. Stop worrying*

Add it in to your project, Then add it your Bundle resources

[image: Then add it your Bundle resources]

Comment: Note to self: when I added my custom fonts to this, I chose from the Resources folder (where they already were) so they wouldn't clutter up the left sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and although the responses here are correct, I figured I'd try to give my own version for those who are still confused after reading the posts above :)

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@vimniky/how-to-use-vector-icons-in-your-react-native-project-8212ac6a8f06) to add my custom fonts to the XCode project :

You don't actually have to open XCode to add fonts for iOS. I used VSCode for example.

Here are the steps:

- Go to node_modules>react-native-vector-icons>Fonts

  *You will have to search for it, modules aren't ordered alphabetically*
- Copy all the fonts available
- Go to your ios folder and create a *new* folder called "Fonts"

   *Watch out ! The naming is case-sensitive, make sure you use a capital "F" (I didn't and spent too much time figuring out where I went wrong)*
- Paste de fonts you copied before in your Fonts folder
- Next open your info.plist file (It's located in ios>Your_Project_Name>info.plist)
- For each new font you added in the Fonts folder, add a line such as the one below, under the key *UIAppFonts*

> The final result should look something like this:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
     <array>
        <string>font1.ttf</string>
        <string>font1.ttf</string>
        <string>[Add your font names here]</string>
    </array>
```

- Finally close the iOS simulator, run *pod install* in the ios folder and run *npm install* in your root (for good measure) and then you can run *react-native run-ios* again.

**If you're using a recent version of React-Native do not use *react-native link* command as you will encounter *duplicate* errors**

Comment: It's better to have the content of the resource in the answer rather than a link, because that will stay over time whereas a link to an external resource may not.

Answer (score 2):

2021 answer with
"react-native": "0.65.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "8.1.0"

Running react native often doesn't work.
it create a duplicate resource declaration and you need to delete the extra lines.
Plus, when you run react-native link manually, it will fix your android but when you run your ios, the build will say you need to unlink it, we will fix this as well.

run:

`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

go to your ios->Podfile

delete this line (fix the unlink issue):

`pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'`

go to ios->YOUR_PROJECT.xcodeproj->project.pbxproj

and delete these lines in the "PBXResourcesBuildPhase" section:

```
            939BE13DDBD94B1FA64AA9EC /* AntDesign.ttf in Resources */,
            E863EAC557374C78B1C1A44F /* Entypo.ttf in Resources */,
            AA1DC0C0FC504FF98744B883 /* EvilIcons.ttf in Resources */,
            76E382E015E1470A9FDE5E08 /* Feather.ttf in Resources */,
            99E9B4823AAE456C89BF6DAF /* FontAwesome.ttf in Resources */,
            BCE22C5804AD4EC988CB4AD6 /* FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf in Resources */,
            FE4AA6C0F54D4A26A2088CDA /* FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf in Resources */,
            096B6D92BD5F4B59A1D262BE /* FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf in Resources */,
            1031EC31F55B40378CAD9D3D /* Fontisto.ttf in Resources */,
            2815970EABC94327BA107658 /* Foundation.ttf in Resources */,
            3CB0C5395AE44CEAB966AE51 /* Ionicons.ttf in Resources */,
            76E538C39D604AC4A0EAE522 /* MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf in Resources */,
            AC62C33B70D04559AC57B231 /* MaterialIcons.ttf in Resources */,
            49299510939246209A803546 /* Octicons.ttf in Resources */,
            6AF5C757975E45839F276B17 /* SimpleLineIcons.ttf in Resources */,
            45F326492D5E453E99A6EEAA /* Zocial.ttf in Resources */,
```

Comment: This still works in 2022 with "react-native": "0.68.0", "react-native-vector-icons": "9.1.0". Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error about Inter-Regular font not being recognised.

1. The first thing I did was downloading the google fonts https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter and find the ttf file for the font missing.
2. Then drag the font file to the src/assets/fonts.
3. Open xcode, click projects name and under build phases you have to locate the font file under Copy Bundle Resource (click the + below the existing list).
4. Add Inter-Regular.ttf under UIAppFonts on your infor.plist file.
5. rm -rf node_modules; watchman watch-del-all; rm -rf /tmp/metro-*; yarn install; npx pod-install || cd ios && pod install; cd ..; react-native start --reset-cache, 4. re-run simulator

Comment: solved my issue. using RN@0.70

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the Font in "Copy Bundle Resources" under "Build Phases"
2. Add the Font in `Info.plist` file
3. If you have added the name of the font `AvenirMedium`, it wont work, you need to use `Avenir-Medium` then it will work in iOS.

Clean previous build and start a fresh one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the name of the ttf file was wrong.
I had to edit **ios/MyApp/Info.plist** and change manually the filename of the font.

From:

```
...
<array>
  <string>Roboto_medium.ttf</string>
...
```

To:

```
...
<array>
  <string>Roboto-Medium.ttf</string>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, specify your fonts this way, map them into three styles:

For instance *Gilroy-SemiBoldItalic*

```
// iOS
{
  fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
  fontWeight: '600',
  fontStyle: 'italic'
}

// Android
{
  fontFamily: 'Gilroy-SemiBoldItalic'
}
```

You can also create a function to generate styles for a font with given weight and style.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it worked fine in Android but not in iOS. The font file name was `PlayfairDisplay-VariableFont_wght.ttf`. But when I opened that file I saw the name as:

[image: exact name].

So, I changed the file name to `PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf` and it worked pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was that I forgot to add the target for the font. If you don't add target for the font it won't work.

Comment: this. Also, you can find the checkbox for the target when you select the font under the `Fonts/` directory in Xcode. The panel shows up on the right side of the window. You want to check your app name under "Target Membership".

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.m` in your iOS folder.

```
NSArray *fontFamilyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
for (NSString *familyName in fontFamilyNames) {
    NSLog(@"Font Family Name = %@", familyName);
    NSArray *names = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    NSLog(@"Font Names = %@", names);
}
```

It's going to list out all the Font-families available in your iOS app.

After that just search for your font-family in your case `LinBiolinum_R`.

After that copy the name and make a condition in your font file like this

```
Platform.OS === "ios" ? "Listed in Console" : "Normal Font family"
```

Remove the script from AppDelegate.m afterwards.

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'fontFamilies'

Comment: here is a gist how to log properly https://gist.github.com/jpavley/6567674

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to solve this issue on the ios build:

```
1- First install the Font on your Mac.

2- Check "My Fonts" in FontBook to make sure the Font is installed.
```

[image]

```
3- Now Press CMD+I to see the Font Postscript name. This should be the 
name of your Font file in your Project.

For example: I was using a font named "Nazegul" and I was getting the 
same error because I had saved the font file name in my project with 
"Nazegul-Regular.ttf" but when I checked this font Postscript name it 
was "NazegulRegular" and after changing the font name to Postscript 
name, the error was gone.
```

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the font files and re-ran `react-native link` and ended up in this state.

I resolved it by ensuring the old fonts were removed from the *Resources* folder and `Info.plist` and then ran the build again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running react-native ios simulator, you should include fonts in the xcode project directory.

**react-native link react-native-vector-icons** doing so , 
will add the fonts to Resources folder in xcode project and also add fonts to pinfo list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I checked if I've added the fonts correctly to the xcode project. Then I checked the info.plist.

Turned out I spelled the name wrong. Instead of FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf, I had written FontAwesoem5_Solid.ttf. So I fixed it. That solved the problem for me.

To sum up - be very careful when typing the names and when checking them.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all pieces of advise, but the problem was that I wrote

```
'./assets/fonts'
```

instead of

`'./src/assets/fonts'`.

Don't forget **rebuild your app** after **'yarn react-native link'**. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've added the fonts in the following way, and it is working.

`react-native.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts'],
};
```

My fonts are located in `./src/assets/fonts` and I've the following fonts: `Urbanist-Bold`, `Urbanist-ExtraBold`, `Urbanist-Light`

My info.plist is looking like this:

```
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Urbanist-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Urbanist-ExtraBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Urbanist-Light.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with `react-native-vector-icons` where it displayed a box with a question mark. Fortunately, I resolved the problem by navigating to the `ios/{project_name/Info.plist` file and adding the following lines inside the `<array>`:

```
<string>Zocial.ttf</string>
<string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Octicons.ttf</string>
<string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
<string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
<string>Foundation.ttf</string>
<string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
<string>Feather.ttf</string>
<string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Entypo.ttf</string>
<string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
```

Additionally, I created a `Fonts` folder within the `ios` directory and placed the corresponding `TTF` files in it. After doing this, make sure to rebuild, close Xcode, and remove the build folder from the ios directory in Visual Studio Code or any other IDE. Open Xcode again, rebuild the project, and this should solve the issue. Now you can use icons in your code like this:

```
import FeatherIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";

<FeatherIcon size={24} color={colors.text} name={'box'}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by just opening the project in Xcode and under Resources folder in Project Navigator, there were duplicate fonts and just removing them from Resources folder and Info.plist both, the issue got resolved. Just run the app in Xcode after deletion then you may verify in your other tools as well without reinstalling npm. Just run 'react-native run-ios', cheers :)