# React-Native, Custom fonts

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use custom fonts in React-Native.

I have ran both `react-native link` and `npx react-native link` multiple times.

My error:
[image: Error shown]

My `react-native.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ["./src/assets/fonts"]
};
```

My styling:

```
fontFamily: 'ProximaNova-Regular'
```

My react dependency versions:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.2",
```

[image: Image of fonts]

Comment: Use git diff to check what change react-native link is doing. Ideally you would have see changes in ios's info.plist file. follow this: https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e

Comment: It doesnt work.

Comment: were those fonts added in info.plist?

Comment: When i run ``react-native link``it doesn't automaticly - I added the fonts to it as it should be myself. But i still cant get it to work.

Comment: Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410354/unrecognized-font-family-on-ios-simulator-with-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by completely uninstalling the fonts from my project, and then reinstallingn carefully making sure everything was correct.

If you have had the same issues written in my question, do like i did and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking manually! Sometimes automatic linking does not do the job properly