# Unrecognized font family 'Saman' on iOS simulator with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a font saman.ttf https://www.dafont.com/samarkan.font in my project. The font is working fine with android but on ios throwing this error.
I tried all the things mentioned in this link
[Unrecognized font family on iOS simulator with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410354/unrecognized-font-family-on-ios-simulator-with-react-native) and below things too

1. cleaning the build.
2. adding font file to info.plist
3. font file included in the Target in XCode
4. font file included in "Copy Bundle Resources"
5. try changing file name to SAMAN___.TTF

Kindly help!

[image: this is the error]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try with this link: https://medium.com/@mehrankhandev/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

Comment: Thanku Shiv Kumar Singh.. It worked!